# Excel 2013 VBA use successive columns to sort large range

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, excel-2013

I've tried to research why this isn't working, but I've hit a wall, because, so far as I can tell, my code ought to be doing the trick...

My situation is that I'm building a spreadsheet to simplify a budget reporting process for my office. As I'm the only one with a half-decent understanding of Excel, I want to make this as braindead and simple for the other users as possible. To that end, *VBA to the rescue!* as it will take care of importing the data and doing all the sorting for me (them) with just one click.

The imported data is 24 columns wide and may grow to as much as 2500 lines by year-end. Once the data is imported, I need to sort by mulitple column types, one after the other, sucessively. So:
- Import data
- sort by date
- sort by transacation type
- sort by billed budget
- etc (6 sorts total)

This is my code at the moment:

```
Sub RefreshAll()
    Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).RefreshAll

    With Worksheets("Detailed Budget Report")
        .Range("RC_number").CurrentRegion.Sort _
            key1:=Range("Sort_1st"), order1:=xlAscending, _
            key2:=Range("Sort_2nd"), order2:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

The **refresh all** will pull from the import file anew, to make sure the spreadsheet is up-to-date. Then, I've got to sort it all. Thanks to the brilliant response at the bottom of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571923/sorting-worksheet-data-by-column-values-using-excel-vba), I learned about using range names, and [this page](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2021718&seqNum=5) showed me how to reference other worksheets.

Here's the problem: only the first sort key is working. The code doesn't throw an error, it doesn't halt, it *appears* to execute correctly. But, only the first sort argument gets actioned; no matter what range I input as the first key, nor what range I enter as the second, only the first gets sorted.

Can anybody help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code to use proper syntax.  Note the difference.

```
Sub RefreshAll()
    Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).RefreshAll

    With Worksheets("Detailed Budget Report").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Sort_1st"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Sort_2nd"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange Range("RC_number")
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Reminder: `.SortFields.Clear` may seem redundant but if you are applying multiple different sorts to the same sheet it can save some headache.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work... I got the following error:
`Run-time error '1004':
The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank.`

Comment: It's not "proper syntax". It's a different sort method based on the `Worksheet.Sort` property instead of the `Range.Sort` method.

Comment: @robinCTS roger that one. New to the site and lingo.  Just know how to do some stuff.

Comment: @JoshuaFenner Sorry about that. I just thought you might be implying the OP was using the sort incorrectly and thought it needed correction. Looks like you weren't, so everything's good.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why your code doesn't work on your computer as it works perfectly on mine. (I *am* running Excel 2007, though.)

In fact, all three of the appropriate methods (out of five total) to perform a sort in Excel work fine for me.

This is the one you haven't seen yet, using `AutoFilter.Sort`:

```
Sub RefreshAll_RS()
  Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).RefreshAll

  With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Detailed Budget Report")
    .Range("RC_number").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
    .Range("RC_number").Select
    With .AutoFilter.Sort
      .Header = xlYes
      .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Sort_2nd"), Order:=xlAscending
      .Apply
      .SortFields.Clear
      .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Sort_1st"), Order:=xlAscending
      .Apply
    End With
    .Range("RC_number").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
  End With
End Sub
```

Then there's your version, using `Range.Sort`. (I've modified it slightly but it's still functionally equivalent.)

```
Sub RefreshAll_Q1()
  Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).RefreshAll

  With Worksheets("Detailed Budget Report").Range("RC_number").CurrentRegion
    .Sort _
      key1:="Sort_1st", order1:=xlAscending, _
      key2:="Sort_2nd", order2:=xlAscending, _
      Header:=xlYes
  End With
End Sub
```

And finally, there's [Joshua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8651782/joshua-fenner)'s version, using `Worksheet.Sort`. (I've fixed the incorrect `.SetRange` parameter bug, so it now works.)

```
Sub RefreshAll_A1()
  Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).RefreshAll

  With Worksheets("Detailed Budget Report").Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Sort_1st"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Sort_2nd"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range("RC_number").CurrentRegion
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Robin. Thank-you for your time. Version _RS throwes the error, `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block not set`, on the `With .AutoFilter.Sort` line.

Version _Q1 runs, but does not sort the second column, only the first (my original problem).

Version _A1 no longer throws an error (thank-you for that), but, as with _Q1, still only sorts the first argument.

I'm strating to think I'm missing something very basic....

Comment: @rdplanglois I highly doubt that different versions of Excel would behave differently for sorting. I suspect you have a corrupted workbook, Excel or OS. Try starting Excel in safe mode, creating a brand new workbook and copying the examples here into it. Then setup some test data manually. The next options, if this still fails, are to try another computer/office installation or re-installing Office/Excel on your computer.

Comment: Thanks Robin. My work-day is done, so, I'll try this with some test data at home. Is it possible that, being an office computer, some portion of the VBA is disabled by the security settings, but that the disablement isn't throwing an error?

Comment: @rdplanglois That seems extremely unlikely. The only thing I can think of is a corruption issue. Unless the workbook is protected?

Comment: I made the workbook myself, so, I know it's not protected. I just got home and made one from scratch, using my original code. It only sorted the first criteria. I tried all your edited ones, and all of them sort only the first criteria too. Then I tried splitting out the the two criteria into separate `With` statements (shoulda thought of that at work), and it *finally* sorted the second criteria as well as the first. I've **no** idea why splitting the sort criteria into separate arguments seems to be necessary, and I feel like there ought to be a more elegant solution, but, there we have it.

Comment: @rdplanglois I originally had the two criteria in separate `With`s too but then thought "there ought to be a more elegant solution" and that's when I rolled them into one! What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Office 2010, on a Windows 7 system.