# Using 2 columns to create an email list where each person gets 1 email

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a formatted spreadsheet where col A is a name, col B is an email, and col C is an event.

Spreadsheet looks like this

```
   A            B             C
person1  person1@gmail.com  party1
person2  person2@gmail.com  party1
person1  person1@gmail.com  party2
```

Using google apps script:

What is the best way to create a mailing list such that each person gets only 1 email and allows me to mention all events they've been to in the same email?

```
My current attempt is:
function sendEmails() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;;   // Number of rows to process

// Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
  var row = data[i];
  var name = row[0];  // First column
  var department = row[1];       // Second column
  var emailAddress = row[2];
  var workshop = row[3];
  var date = row[4];

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "Test Email" , message);
  }
}
```

This will send an email to everyone, however IF the individual is added to multiple events they will receive multiple emails.

Any Ideas or suggestions for topics to study more?

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the sheet by column A or B first? That could make the rest much simpler.

Comment: Also, if two persons have the same email, are you supposed to send a second email? Or may you assume that will never happen?  Probably you want to sort on col b and a. Then write your email, but do not send until you are on the last row or the next row has a new addressee

Comment: Sort could be manual or along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571923/sorting-worksheet-data-by-column-values-using-excel-vba

Comment: Also where is message declared or built?

Comment: Jeremy,  any sort can be done. I'm trying to avoid sending a second email. and just include the information into the 1 email. The message for the email will be using the data from the cells to personalize. 
So, the format of the email would look like, "hello person2, last month you came to party2" etc etc.

In order to not spam person1 with two identical emails. I want to send them 1 email that says, "Hello person1, last month you came to party1, and party 2"

In my own thinking, Is there a way to combine cells so that person1 C column would look like party1, party2 instead of two entries

Comment: Yes, that is what the textjoin function does. But the challenge is to feed it the right range of cells. But then for sure sort so that you can specify a contiguous range in column c with the results in D. The script could determine which rows have the same email address by seeing when they change or end. There may be a way to that with IF in the spreadsheet (and now that I think about it, COUNTIF might also do the trick).

Comment: did it. Do not have the time to write it up as a proper answer now, but see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IxrkwlALO6MnyLA8Zs5LqUIMd-ePqZACNN92sDnuCnU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes this is perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal here was to within the spreadsheet create the desired event list once per e-mail. Once that is there, doing the emailing script would run down the event column, and where it finds a list, look back to whom to email it.
I sorted by email so things bunched together by email (we were told not to worry about multiple people with the same email, so no need to sort by that too).
I tried to build up the answer in parts so it would not be thoroughly impenetrable and so I could test the pieces.
Step 1 was to add header rows to the sheet so that first of all I did not need to make a special case to say the first email was new. I also described these.

```
name    email   event   new email?  num events for this email   event range text
```

as the column headers in A through G (row 1).
Columns A through C were as given.
Column D, new email, indicated whether this is the first occurrence of this  email, which because things are sorted is equivalent to checking if the row above it is not the same. The (draggable) formula I used for that was

```
=not((indirect("B"&Row()-1))=(indirect("B"&Row())))
```

I needed the number of times the email occurred in order to produce the range for the email, so I calculated that as:

```
=countif(B:B,"="&B2)
```

and dragged it down so the B2 changed to B3, B4, ...

Then for the first row in which the particular email occurred, I calculated the range by adding this count to the current row and subtracting 1. This was done by:

```
=if(indirect("d"&row()),"C"&Row()&":C"& (row()+indirect("e"&row())-1),"")
```

(this is the same all the way down column F. And finally in column G I put together the text for each item in the range, again only in thew first row for the given email. That formula was:

```
=if(indirect("d"&row()),textjoin(", ",true,indirect(indirect("f"&row()))),"")
```

where `indirect("d"&row())` tells whether we are in the first row of the email, so we must construct the text (and otherwise leave the cell blank). The textjoin does what it says, with true telling it to skip empty events. Then the first indirect picks out the string with the range (e.g., "C2:C4") and the second then gets the content of the range (series of 3 events in this example). This column then contains the desired event list.

One could instead build much or all of this logic into the function instead.

For now I have an example of this for viewing at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IxrkwlALO6MnyLA8Zs5LqUIMd-ePqZACNN92sDnuCnU/edit#gid=0
though I am not promising to keep it there forever.

Comment: There would also be ways to do this with OFFSET